# cdrtools and dvd+rw tools installing issue in am5728 linux kernel?

Tags: linux, dvd, embedded, dvd-burning, embedded-linux

I am installing dvd+rw-tools-7.1 and Cdrtools-3.02a09 in am335x using below commands
1.dvd+rw-tools-7.1
root@am57xx-evm:/dvd+rw-tools-7.1#sed -i '/stat.h/a #include <sys/sysmacros.h>' growisofs.c &&
sed -i '/stdlib/a #include <limits.h>' transport.hxx &&
make all rpl8 btcflash

root@am57xx-evm:/dvd+rw-tools-7.1#make prefix=/usr install &&
install -v -m644 -D index.html 
/usr/share/doc/dvd+rw-tools-7.1/index.html
2.cdrtools
root@am57xx-evm:/cdrtools-3.02#export GMAKE_NOWARN=true &&
make -j1 INS_BASE=/usr DEFINSUSR=root DEFINSGRP=root
root@am57xx-evm:/cdrtools-3.02#export GMAKE_NOWARN=true &&
make INS_BASE=/usr MANSUFF_LIB=3cdr DEFINSUSR=root DEFINSGRP=root install &&
install -v -m755 -d /usr/share/doc/cdrtools-3.02a09 &&
install -v -m644 README.* READMEs/* ABOUT doc/*.ps 
/usr/share/doc/cdrtools-3.02a09
pdating cache ./config.cache
creating ./config.status
creating rules.cnf
creating xconfig.h
==> MAKING SYMLINKS in ./RULES/
==> MAKING SYMLINKS in ./TEMPLATES/
sh conf/cc-config.sh cc cc incs/Dcc.armv7l-linux
Trying to find cc
Found cc
Creating empty 'incs/Dcc.armv7l-linux', using cc as default compiler
==> MAKING "all" ON SUBDIRECTORY "SRCROOT/conf"
make[1]: Entering directory '/cdrtools-3.02/conf'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cdrtools-3.02/conf'
==> MAKING "all" ON SUBDIRECTORY "SRCROOT/inc"
make[1]: Entering directory '/cdrtools-3.02/inc'
==> MAKING "all" ON SUBCOMPONENT "SRCROOT/inc/align_test.mk"
make[2]: Entering directory '/cdrtools-3.02/inc'
==> MAKING DIRECTORY "OBJ/armv7l-linux-cc"
==> MAKING DIRECTORY "OBJ/armv7l-linux-cc/man"
==> MAKING DEPENDENCIES "OBJ/armv7l-linux-cc/align_test.d"
make[2]: Warning: File '/usr/include/stdc-predef.h' has modification time 8494 s in the future
==> MAKING DEPENDENCIES "OBJ/armv7l-linux-cc/align_test.d"
make[2]: Warning: File '/usr/include/stdc-predef.h' has modification time 8494 s in the future
==> MAKING DEPENDENCIES "OBJ/armv7l-linux-cc/align_test.d"

But not installing properly how to install in am572x board
i am using u-boot v2019.01 and linux kernel v4.19.59 and ti-sdk-am57xxevm-06.01.00.08
Could you give me suggestions for how to install these to in am5728 board,
Thanking you,

Regards,
Ramachandra.